# Split string using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to split the string in to two strings

```
 INPUT: "ASSO|ASSOCS|AS|ASSOCIATES/ASSOC/"

OUTPUT: "ASSO|ASSOCS|AS|ASSOCIATES","ASSOC"
```

Tried :
I tried removing the the last character "`/"` first and replaced the other with `","`. Wanted to know can we do this both steps in once using regex

```
str=str.replace(/\/$/, "")
str=str.replace(\/,",")
```

Comment: You can simply use `filter(None, str.split('/'))`

Comment: `print(",".join(filter(None, INPUT.split('/'))))`

Comment: Or `re.findall(r"[^/]+", s)`

Comment: are you perhaps looking for [`re.finditer("(.+?)/", INPUT)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer)?

Answer (score 1):

If you are "trying to split the string in to two strings", then you could do

```
s = "ASSO|ASSOCS|AS|ASSOCIATES/ASSOC/"
s1, s2, _ = s.split('/')
```

Comment: This is generally a better option than regex. I would personally assign the output to a list however rather than using argument unpacking. If the list returned from `string.split()` is too short, you'll get an error.